# What exactly is Delta-v?

Tags: rocket-science

What exactly is [Delta-$v$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v)? I am trying to calculate some rocket math. I managed to calculate $\Delta v$ using the rocket equation. Here is my equation:
\begin{equation}
   3433.5 \ln \left(\frac{38.52}{14.52}\right) = 3349.9\:\mathrm{m/s}
\end{equation}
So I know that is the change in velocity, but I don't understand exactly what that means. Does that mean the rocket needs to output propellant at 3349.9m/s before it lifts off and gains altitude? Is it the thrust? I don't quite understand, but I would love if someone would explain it to me. I would be even more grateful if you gave me an example or two of where $\Delta v$ would be used in another rocket related equation. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are deep in interstellar space. With the fuel onboard you are able to change the speed of your spacecraft by $2000 m/s $. That's the delta-v of your spacecraft. The rocket equation used to calculate it is an equation which assumes conditions which aren't really present in real situations: that there is no air drag, that all of the fuel is ejected instantaneously, that gravity doesn't slow the spacecraft etc. 
In real space travel, much more complicated analysis is required to calculate what speed the spacecraft can actually reach and which speed is necessary for a particular orbital maneuver or interplanetary journey.
For more information, Wikipedia has a nice article: [Delta-v](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v?wprov=sfla1)
Also: [Rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation?wprov=sfla1)